# Getting Firefox 112 to show "Recent files" in the upload file selector

Tags: firefox, gtk

I updated my Ubuntu to 22.04 and the Firefox that come with it (FF 112) is no longer showing a "Recent files" entry in the upload file selection dialog (the dialog which is often elicited via a "Browse..." button). Is there a way to reinstate it (didn't see anything obvious in `about:config`)? Is it a problem with Firefox or with some updated GTK file selector?

Comment: 1. Do you mean, "I **updated** my Ubuntu to 22.04..." 2. What is the ""Recent files" entry in the upload file selection dialog"? Do you mean through Send? Send has been discontinued: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-happened-firefox-send  3. Firefox in Windows 22.04 is installed as a SNAP, different from previous Firefox *packages*. That might have changed the profile.

Comment: 1) yes, "updated". 2) No I mean the dialog you get when you need to upload something to any site 3) Still have my bookmarks, passwords, cookies...  so must be the same profile, and if this is a profile change, how can I undo it.